# Почта на сервере не получает письма, а Exim выдает очень странные логи

Tags: email, dns, smtp, exim, exim4

На сервере есть почта primer@domen.ru ,почта с него отлично отправляется и доставляется, но если написать самому себе или же с gmail,yandex то ничего не приходит и ошибок нету при отправке.
В логах нашёл странную активность

```
2023-06-15 13:54:12 no host name found for IP address 141.00.00.000
2023-06-15 13:54:14 no host name found for IP address 80.00.00.000
2023-06-15 13:54:03 auth_login authenticator failed for (User) [80.00.00.000]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=carbon@domen.ru)
2023-06-15 13:54:03 auth_login authenticator failed for (User) [141.00.00.000]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=newsletter@domen.ru)
```

причем auth_login authenticator failed for (User) прямо дофига, этот скрин только за 1 минуту а там их ещё больше
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и почтовые ящики эти все не существуют, а ip почему то используется только тех доменов которые я не использую для почты, да и вообще они просто есть и никак не используются.

В конфиге exim поставил interface = 82.000.00.00 (домен с которого и нужно все отправлять) но нужный для ip 82... вообще не фигурирует в логах, да результата это не дало
DNS домена делегирован на яндексе.
Почтовые, и другие записи все там есть, а на сервере в панели управления DNS есть нюанс "Ошибка при работе с вторичным сервером DNS" и как её исправить я так и не понял.

Нашёл как проверить соединение с вторичным сервером dig domen.ru @82.000.00.00 axfr
в ответ получил в это

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.17-Ubuntu <<>> domen.ru @82.000.00.00 axfr                                         
;; global options: +cmd                                                                                                 
; Transfer failed.
```

и как все это исправлять я честно даже не могу представить, в интернете вообще ничего не нашёл.

Буду рад любой наводке, так как к сожалению в этой сфере доменов и почт я полный ноль.

Comment: Это просто сообщения о том, что на вашем сервере пытаются авторизоваться для использования его как релея для рассылки спама. Это нормально до тех пор, пока пароль не подобрали.

Comment: @user_587 а разве когда кто то пытается авторизоваться ведь его ip должен показываться я просто видел вопрос с такой темой https://forum.ispsystem.ru/showthread.php?24766-Сторонние-попытки-подключения-к-Exim4